# 403 forbidden error in loading css

Tags: python, html, css, flask

I am working on a Flask application. I wrote a small program that have an html file and a css file. I took the css from Font-Awesome.
When I run the program on PyCharm everything works fine but when I do it from the terminal, using `flask run`, in the loading of the page a get this error:
`GET http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/fontawesome-all.min.css 403 (Forbidden)`

and when I try to locate the error it tells me its in this line:
`<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/fontawesome-all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`

My html file is this one:

```
{% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}
{% block title %}Index Page{% endblock %}

{% block styles %}
{{super()}}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/style.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='favicon.ico') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/fontawesome-all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/fontawesome-all.css">
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <body background="/static/kitchen_black.jpg" style="background-size: cover">
        <div class="container" style="text-align: center">
            <h1 style="color: white"><i class="fas fa-utensils"></i><br>
                  Hello, KiMa is here to help you!
            </h1>

            <div class="panel-body">
                <button class="button button1">
                    <a href="{{ url_for('allrecipes') }}" style="color: black">
                          Display all the Recipes</a>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <button class="button button1">
                    <a href="{{ url_for('ingredients') }}" style="color: black">
                      Insert your Ingredients</a>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

{% endblock %}
```

Of course I placed the css files in the static folder
I don't know what it is

EDITED:

I tried using url_for also for the font-awesome.css but no good results. I also tried to include different href for the cdn but again I received errors on those lines. I also removed the .css href and again, from PyCharm everything is smooth and clear, but if I run it from the terminal same error even if I am not including the font-awesome css

Comment: Why are you not using `url_for()` for the CSS files too?

Comment: In fact I'm a bit confused because `static` is not in `href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/fontawesome-all.min.css"`. Does the error message you've posted match the code you're using?

Comment: I get an error too if I try to use http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/fontawesome-all.min.css for a URL. However when I search for "fontawesome cdn" I get URLs like https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css which do work.

Comment: @roganjosh I tried using url_for but still I got that error. And yes that url is inserted automatically once I load the page. I am new to html so I don't know why also that url is loaded.

Comment: @MrLister How I can insert that "stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/…"?

Comment: @AndreaFoderaro What you must do is find the place where it tries to use the maxcdn URL now and replace that with the stackpath URL. Maybe there's an `import` in one of the css files, or a link in bootstrap/base.html?

Comment: Yes @MrLister it was there thanks a lot